# How can I use RegEx to extract info from a html document

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to extract some info from a html document using RegEx (it must be regex not any other html parser). The html document I want to extract from is called: `"website1.html"`. It has this data below:

```
<div class="category"><div class="comedy">Category1</div></div>
   <p class="desc">Title1</p>
   <p class="date">Date1/p>

<div class="category"><div class="comedy">Category2</div></div>
   <p class="desc">Title2</p>
   <p class="date">Date2/p>
```

How could I first select the html document so that python can read it, and then extract the information from: `class="comedy", class="desc", and class="date"` using regex `findall` expressions?

I want them to be in separate lists so that I end up with: `["Title1", "Title2"]` in one list and `["Category1", "Category2"]` in another etc.

I have the overall process mapped in my head but I dont know the specific characters/functions to use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

Comment: instead of Regex use a [`proper web scraper`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish it using `regular expression` as the following example:

```
import re

filename = 'path\\website1.html'
t = open(filename, "r").read()

categories = re.findall(r"<div class=\"comedy\">(.*?)</div>",t)
descs = re.findall(r"<p class=\"desc\">(.*?)</p>",t)
dates = re.findall(r"<p class=\"date\">(.*?)/p>",t)

# Print Your code here
print(categories)
print(descs)
print(dates)
```

**the result**:

```
['Category1', 'Category2']
['Title1', 'Title2']
['Date1', 'Date2']
```

but I noted that your html is not well formatted (`<p class="date">Date2/p>`) I do it according to your example.

Comment: How can I make it so it extracts information straight from HTML file instead of pasting the file into my python script? (What do I put instead of "t")

Comment: @Jason7261 I have been updated the answer  check it.